# Does non-payment of muajjal Haq Mehar has any implication on Nikkah or Validity of Marriage?

Tags: halal-haram

I am happily married for five years and have two kids now alhumdulillah. Recently I got to know about the muajjal (to be paid Immediately) and ghaire mu'ajjal. My Haq Mehar was fixed but I didnt knew that there is muajjal and ghair maujjal thing? I was like Haq Mehar is paid when the divorce occurs. Neither my wife has demanded the haq mehar from me. Does this has any implication on my nikkah or marriage?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you delay what is her right? What if she passes away before you had a chance to give her the mahr due to her?

Comment: Muajjal sadaaq was not the sunnah of the prophet nor his sahabah, but it is regarded as permissible because sadaq is no condition for the validity of nikah. But it is highly recommended to pay it as soon as possible because once nikah was consumed it is a due on the husband. And scholars hold different views on its permissibiliy fir example in the Maliki school of fiqh it is highly disliked without a strong reason.